# Why do we allow functions with empty domains?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I understand that we can define functions in terms of sets and ordered pairs and then for each set $A$ the triple $(\emptyset,A,\emptyset)$ is a function. On the other hand, if we think of a function as an assignment (and I assume that this is the intuition that everyone should have), then there doesn't seem to be much sense in allowing the domain to be empty. Are there some good reasons to still do so?

Comment: For one, it formally meets the exact definition of function $f: A \to B$ as a **subset** $f$ of $A \times B$ satisfying certain (in this case, vacuous) rules.

Comment: @Randall That's what I was trying to say with my first sentence :)

Comment: Right, and that's all you need.  It meets the definition.  Your second interpretation is the usual way to think about functions with non-empty domains.  This is sometimes needed to make certain counting identities easier to write down, or to make certain algebraic structures complete.

Comment: Is there a reason you want a function to *not* have an empty domain? In that case, how can $\bf Set$ be a category, if the identity function $\varnothing\to\varnothing$ is not a function?

Comment: @AsafKaragila "In that case, how can Set be a category, if the identity function $\emptyset\to\emptyset$ is not a function?" -  This sounds like a possible source of motivation. Why do I want $\bf Set$ to be a catergory? Why not adapt the definition of a category?

Comment: @Randall "This is sometimes needed to make certain counting identities easier to write down, or to make certain algebraic structures complete." -  This is the kind of answer I was looking for :)

Comment: Because other categories might not have "empty sets", but they sure as hell might have other initial objects (e.g. trivial group; prime field; etc.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Please correct me if I am wrong: There is no group or field such that the associated set is empty, so the actual motivation is that we want all categories to have initial objects. (I have to admit that I don't know what an initial object is.)

Comment: What's wrong with the idea of an assignment for empty functions? For each of the 0 elements of the domain, the function assigns a result.

Comment: @DanDoel "For each of the $0$ elements, the function assigns a result" - So the "function" doesn't assign anything at all :)

Comment: @Filippo: The "empty field" is the field generated by the empty set, which is, in a given category of "fields of characteristics $p$", the prime field of that category. Think of it as "the vector space over $K$", which one is the vector space spanned by the empty set? It is not an empty set, it is the trivial space. And this is *exactly* the reason for using the term "initial object" rather than "empty object".

Comment: @Filippo That's not a very good rejoinder. It's essentially the argument one might use to insist that 0 is not a number, or that the empty set isn't a set. Including these 'degenerate' objects usually simplifies statements relevant to the theory. So, there needs to be a better reason to exclude them than a mere refusal to expand one's intuition in a pretty straight forward way.

Comment: I.E. frequently, some statement, "forall/exists $S$ and $f : S → A$ ..." will result in $S = ø$ together with the empty function automatically covering important corner cases, which would otherwise have to be explicitly stated if the empty function were arbitrarily excluded.

Comment: @DanDoel "It's essentially the argument one might use to insist that 0 is not a number, or that the empty set isn't a set." - Very nice remark!

Comment: @DanDoel Regarding your last comment, could you please give an example?

Comment: You can generate examples from algebra, similar to what Asaf Karaglia was pointing to. E.G. for every set $S$ there is a free monoid/group/ring/etc. $F(S)$, such that homomorphisms $F(S) → R$ correspond exactly to functions $S → U(R)$, where $U(R)$ is the carrier set of $R$. When $S = ø$ you get the initial monoid/group/ring, with exactly one homomorphism to every other such object. The initial algebra has no generators, and the unique homomorphism out of it corresponds to the unique function mapping its 0 generators into the result.